# Iterating a vectors that are contained in a struct

Tags: c++, string, vector

Struct that has multiple vectors within

```
struct data {
    //char array1[20];
    //char array2[20];
    //char array3[20];

    vector<string> playerID1;
    vector<string> playerID2;
    vector<string> overall;
}P1;

struct data P(string b) {

    int i = 0;
    player_attributes *tmp = new player_attributes;

    tmp = head;

    while (tmp != NULL) {

        if (tmp->potential == b)
        {

            tmp->Id1 = P1.playerID1[i];
            tmp->Id2 = P1.playerID2[i];
            tmp->overrall_rating = P1.overall[i];
            i++;
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }

        return P1;
    }
}
```

I used `i++` initially but I kept getting a vector subscript error.
I really don't know how to iterator this to store values and access them later on.

Comment: As provided, your code won't compile. `P1.overall[it];` is suspect...

Comment: There are 2 `i++` in the loop. That likely got you when you were using `i`

Comment: @Jarod42 But.. There is `P1` defined..

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: indeed `P1` is defined, but still code won't compile

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: *"You are incrementing `i` multiple times per iteration of for loop"*, as there is a `return` in middle, no.

Comment: This is what i had initially and got the error, ik that that's not the way to iterate a vector but IDK how to iterate multiple vectors at the same time.

Comment: @DanielMangal: edit your question instead of adding comment which "fix" your question.

Comment: `player_attributes *tmp = new player_attributes; tmp = head;` is a memory leak.

Comment: okay, so is the memory leak the problem? pls check out the new edit and tell me what's wrong with the iterator. I am using visual studio and i keep getting the error "vector subscription out of range"

Comment: if you want help you need to post a [mcve], the code you posted isn't compilable. what is `head`? what is `player_attributes`? what is the contents of the `playerID1`, `playerID2` and `overall` vectors?

Comment: This code is part of a bigger program. Head is the start of a linklist containing strings.`Player_attributes` is a struct of strings. The vectors contain multiple strings. All I would like to know is how to iterate multiple vectors at the same time.

Comment: assuming your link list is the same length or shorter than the length of your vectors your code should work, some bounds checking would be a good idea though

Answer (score 0):

You get error when `i` reaches end of vector. `std::vector< >::operator[]`  does not do bound checking and does not create new elements. You have to make sure that you stop when end of vector reached.

Also, why struct of vectors? Why not a vector of structs? Organize it in this way:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using std::string;
using std::vector;

struct data {
    string playerID1;
    string playerID2;
    string overall;

    data(const string &i1, const string &i2, const string &ov): 
        playerID1(i1),playerID2(i2),overall(ov) {}
};

vector<data> P1;

// a little demonsration
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    P1.emplace_back("", "","test1"); 
    P1.emplace_back("", "","test2"); 

    for(auto it = P1.begin(); it != P1.end(); it++ )
    {
        std::cout << it->overall << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: @DanielMangal uh, you have `vector::size()`, you have iterators `begin()\end()`...did you even checked what vector is? cppreference.com? ANd there is your design flaw that nothing guarantees that vectors are of same size

Comment: any idea how to make them the same size

Comment: @DanielMangal vector of structs - see my answer. That way you also can reuse single record (data) elsewhere

Comment: i am getting an error on "vector<data> p1;" "data is ambiguous